# Create and fill a 10 bits set from two 8 bits characters

Tags: c++

We have 2 characters `a` and b of `8` bits that we want to encode in a 10 bits set. What we want to do is take the first `8` bits of character `a` put them in the first 8 bits of the 10 bits set. Then take only the first `2`  bits of character `b` and fill the rest.

[image]

**QUESTION:** Do I need to shift the 8 bits in order to concatenate the other 2 ?

```
// Online C++ compiler to run C++ program online
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

struct uint10_t {
    uint16_t value : 10;
    uint16_t _     : 6;
};

uint10_t hash(char a, char b){
    uint10_t hashed;
    // Concatenate 2 bits to the other 8
    hashed.value = (a << 8) + (b & 11000000);
    return hashed;
}

int main() {
   uint10_t hashed = hash('a', 'b');
   std::bitset<10> newVal = hashed.value;
   std::cout << newVal << "  "<<hashed .value << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Thanks @Scheff's Cat. My cat says Hi
[image]

Comment: The image is a bit misleading. What's the expected output?

Comment: The diagram is confusing.  I don't see how the bits in the result relate to the bits in `a` and `b`.

Comment: It's because It's wrong apparently. I based the diagram on the code response.  I thought it was right tho. @Scheff'sCat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I need to shift the 8 bits in order to concatenate the other 2?

Yes.

The bits of `a` have to be shifted left to make room for the two bits of `b`. As there is room needed for two bits a left shift by 2 is appropriate. (Before my recent update, there was a wrong left shift by 8 which I didn't notice. Shame on me.)

The bits of `b` have to be shifted right. The reason is that OP wants to combine the two *most* significant bits of `b` with them of `a`. As these two bits have to appear as *least* significant bits in the result they have to be shifted to that position.

It should be:

```
hashed.value = (a << 2) + ((b & 0xc0) >> 6);
```

or

```
hashed.value = (a << 2) + ((b & 0b11000000) >> 6);
```

As `b` is of type `char` (which is signed or unsigned depending on the compiler), it is even better to swap the order of `&` and `>>`:

```
hashed.value = (a << 2) + ((b >> 6) & 0x03);
```

or

```
hashed.value = (a << 2) + ((b >> 6) & 0b11);
```

This ensures that any possible sign bit extension is eliminated which may occur if the type `char` is a signed type in the specific compiler and `b` has a negative value (i.e. the most significant bit is set and will be replicated in the conversion to `int`).

[MCVE on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/af036d6e6bc5b667):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

struct uint10_t {
    uint16_t value : 10;
    uint16_t _     : 6;
};

uint10_t hash(char a, char b){
    uint10_t hashed;
    // Concatenate 2 bits to the other 8
    hashed.value = (a << 2) + ((b >> 6) & 0b11);
    return hashed;
}

int main() {
    uint10_t hashed = hash('a', 'b');
    std::cout << "a: " << std::bitset<8>('a') << '\n';
    std::cout << "b:         " << std::bitset<8>('b') << '\n';
    std::bitset<10> newVal = hashed.value;
    std::cout << "   " << newVal << "  " << hashed.value << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
a: 01100001
b:         01100010
   0110000101  389
```

One may wonder why the two upper bits of `a` are not lost although `a` is of type `char` which is usually an 8 bit type. The reason is that integral arithmetic operations work at least on `int` types. Hence, `a << 2` involves the implicit conversion of `a` to `int` which has at least 16 bit.

Comment: Hey Scheff's cat. Meow Meow. Why didn't you do shift right ? sheesh I had to ask

Comment: @HaniGotc Now, where you ask I wonder myself what I was writing. I made a [new attempt on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/68ed8f5a93c84a34). I'm afraid I have to review my answer...

Comment: @HaniGotc While reviewing the sample on coliru, I added some formatting to the output. I strongly believe the result looks much more reasonable now.